# Get text from a section on some page

Tags: api, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I know how to make an API call to get me the text of the whole page, like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvlimit=1&rvprop=content&format=xml&titles=Stack%20Overflow), but is there a way (without having to parse through the wiki markup) to only get the text from a certain section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation for the `revisions` module](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aProperties#revisions_.2F_rv), you'll notice that it has a prameter `rvsection`, which is exactly what you want. So, for example, to retrieve the lead section, use

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&titles=Stack%20Overflow&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0